# How to search in freebase by mid

Tags: freebase

I have just dumped the data from Freebase, but when I see in the data I see "/m/03lp844" which is mid. But how am I going to get more detail out of that mid? I can't find anything on the documentation.

So, I dumped film data and when I look for actors, it only shows a bunch of mids, but I need actors name as well.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [Freebase schema](http://www.freebase.com/schema/film/film?domain=/film) so that you understand how things are connected to each other. In the case of films and actors, they are connected together by an intermediary node /film/performance.  You'll need to follow the link from the films to those nodes and from there to the linked actor (and look at the actor's /type/object/name property).

Comment: Hi Thanks for you answer, but I still don't quite understand. How do I follow the link in the search service. Sorry, it's just that when I look at the search result and I don't know where to go next.

Comment: So "dumped film data" means "used the search service"?  Can you provide an example of what you're doing now?

Comment: Hi, so i go directly to this http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/browse/film/ and download film.tsv. If i open that in google refine on column starring, it shows me just mids, which i would like to get more information from mids from that column.

Comment: Did you look at the schema?  If you are using that style dump (which is supposed to be going away soon), /film/performance translates to peformance.tsv in the same directory that you found film.tsv for /film/film.  If you search for the MID from the Performance column of film.tsv, you'll find a line like:         /m/0k6fsl       Shelley Duvall  The Shining             Wendy Torrance
 with the actor, the film, and the character.

Comment: Oh, I see it now thanks a lot. One last question, can google refine look up mid from performance.tsv and merge the name into film.tsv?

Answer (score 1):

The mid is an uniq id for every object in freebase.
So you will see a lot of edges pointing to other mids.
Indeed, I think only when the linked information is not simple values like string, number, etc, it will be a mid.
One easy way to look what those mid refer to is using the rdf api:
you could query by key /en/michael_jordan :
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/rdf/en/michael_jordan
or you could query by mids:
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/rdf/m/054c1
and you could get the name of actors names using the "rdfs:name" edge.
The result RDF api shown to you should be familiar.They are all the triples start with the key or mid in the freebase dump.

other interesting apis are here:
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/API
you can search, fetch description, find everything related to a mid, etc.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can you Freebase's MQLRead api, for example, this would return an json string about all "common topic" about "micheal jordan"

[https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={"id":"/en/michael_jordan","limit":1,"*":null,"type":"/common/topic"}](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%7B%22id%22%3a%22/en/michael_jordan%22,%22limit%22:1,%22%2a%22%3anull,%22type%22%3a%22/common/topic%22%7D)

This would show all the types that /en/micheal_jordan has.

[https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={"id":"/en/michael_jordan","limit":1,"*":null}](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%7B%22id%22%3a%22/en/michael_jordan%22,%22limit%22:1,%22%2a%22%3anull%7D)